# CloudKit Error - Public Server Latency

Tags: cloudkit, latency

CloudKit has been working fine for me so far, but tonight I am unable to perform even small basic queries. I am getting errors that look like:

```
error:
INTERNAL_ERROR
operation:
record query
database:
public
server latency:
10040ms
request size:
160B
response size:
0B
requestId:???
```

I searched this site and Google and found nothing helpful in this area. I have no idea what it causing this error or how to go about fixing it.

Is this an error I am somehow causing myself? Or is server latency unrelated to anything we can control? Is it possible to update CloudKit too often? How can I find out if I am being throttled in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens sometimes leading up to WWDC, which happens the first week of June. I had some sporadic CloudKit issues (slow/failed fetches) around this time last year.

Other times it's no more than a hiccup, and CloudKit may return a 'retry after' value in the completion block. That can be passed back into the function.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerrorretryafterkey

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, in this case, it was a server related issue that was completely out of my control and not due to throttling. Waiting one night helped to solve the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it.